# USB Device not working randomly in USB HUB

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, microphone, 21.04

I have this issue that started happening 2 days ago. 2 of my USB devices just stopped working while connected to a USB hub. Both devices have some audio related features. Webcam with a microphone and one external DAC for XLR microphone input and output audio.

When I plug the devices into a USB port directly to the laptop dock or laptop USB ports, the devices works fine, but when I plug them back in the USB hub they can't be used.

The DAC output is detected but doesn't work. The DAC input is not dectected. The webcam is not detected and block any application that uses a webcam to open (Cheese, Teams, etc.)

All of this worked fine a few days ago.

I tried to reset pulse audio config by deleting the `pulse` folder in the `.config` folder. I tried to reboot many times, with and without the devices plugged in.

Changing computer to a Windows machine seems to work fine so it rules out the hub as the source of the problem.

What can I do ? And how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running sudo apt update and if any packages are upgradeable upgrade them and if not try using a different usb hub if you have one and also try using different ports on the hub and if that doesn't work try using a different port on the laptop for the hub and also try the hub on a different ubuntu device running 21.04

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. Changing the USB port the hub is using on the laptop fix the thing. Never though it was that. Thanks a lot

Comment: glad i could help